# Django - How can add multiple forms according to input enter number or with click add more button

Tags: python, django

I have an input field where the will customer add a number for buy membership then will get forms according to numbers 1,2, or 5 then will show 1,2, or 5 forms with input fields in which will add data.

How can add this type of functionality? Because I'm a beginner in python Django. Thanks

For example:

1. customer will come to the site and click on buy membership
2. the first page will How many Memberships do you want to buy?  ==> input Field in which add 1,2, or 5
3. based on how many members enter a show a page to collect information of members
4. 3rd step collect customer/parent information

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how much you've progressed in this, because your question is not exactly straight forward. However, I'll give you a general guideline on how to make something like this work. you can find out how to do each step by searching in django docs.

1. create a form (e.g. MembershipNumForm). This form will have a single field, which is the number of memberships.
2. Write a view that gets this form's data via post and redirects to some 'MembershipDetails page.
3. Create another form (e.g.MembershipDetailsForm), which gets membership details.
4. Write the MembershipDetails view. this view gets a number in its url (e.g. /membershipdetails/2). you pass this number along with MembershipDetailsForm to your template (or whatever front you're using). In this example I used 2, you could use whatever nuumber was passed to the url.
5. In the template, use a for loop to repeat the form based on the number you gave to the template.

There are a lot of ways to make this better, but since your question is vague I gave something general to work with. Hope it solves your problem :)

Comment: Thanks, Dear @eva for replying to me. Sorry because I could not progress in a proper way but you got my problem. Please can you give me an example so that I will work on that with pure logic. Thanks